# How do I open an image in another window in pyqt5 as soon as my app starts in python?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want another window for the image file to be opened as soon as the app loads beside the main window.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

class App(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'LEGO'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480            

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I dont know how to display the image file as soon as my main window opens. I want my image window to be also opened just after my main window is loaded. I am new to pyqt5 please help

Comment: what image?????

Comment: Do you mean a splash screen while the main program loads?

Answer (score 0):

Try the QSplashScreen Class http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html

The example from the docs is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QPixmap pixmap(":/splash.png");
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
    splash.show();
    app.processEvents();
    ...
    QMainWindow window;
    window.show();
    splash.finish(&window);
    return app.exec();
}
```